# Calling Variable in T -SQL

Tags: t-sql

What is diff in below 2 query?? Which one is better in term of performance and why??

```
declare @id varchar(10) ='207054'

declare @query nvarchar(max)

Set @query= 'select top 1 * from practice where externalid=@id'
print @query
Exec Sp_executeSQL @query,N'@id varchar(10)',@id
```

---

```
Set @query= 'Select top 1 * from practice
             where externalid='''+@id+''' '
print @query
Exec Sp_executeSQL @query
```

Comment: Concatenating SQL string is dangerous. SQL Injection example: http://rextester.com/HSO30582

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how `@id` is populated. If the value of that variable comes from the user, the 2nd option opens a huge gaping security hole (see: Sql Injection), while the first does not.

Better to be safe... what today is a known-safe source, suddenly tomorrow is used in an unsafe way, and suddenly your database is hacked. Prefer the first option whenever possible.